# Why ChiSq test and Likelihood Ratio Test are the same when comparing to logistic regression models?

Tags: logistic, anova, chi-squared-test, likelihood-ratio

I am trying to understand `avnoa` on two logistic regression models. I noticed that the chisq (`Chisq`) test and likelihood ratio test (`LRT`) are returning the exact same results in this following toy example. Why?

```
> fit1=glm(am~mpg+hp,mtcars, family = binomial())
> fit2=glm(am~mpg+hp+wt,mtcars, family = binomial())
> anova(fit1,fit2, test="Chisq")
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: am ~ mpg + hp
Model 2: am ~ mpg + hp + wt
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)   
1        29    19.2326                        
2        28     8.7661  1   10.466 0.001216 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> anova(fit1,fit2, test="LRT")
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: am ~ mpg + hp
Model 2: am ~ mpg + hp + wt
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)   
1        29    19.2326                        
2        28     8.7661  1   10.466 0.001216 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likelihood ratio test *is* a (type of) Chi-square test.

The documentation for `?anova.glm` says:

> You can also choose "LRT" and "Rao" for likelihood ratio tests and Rao's efficient score test. The former is synonymous with "Chisq" (although both have an asymptotic chi-square distribution).

Plainly, it is just a poor choice of notation. "Chisq" test is more succinctly said to be a likelihood ratio test.

Comment: @hxd1011 sorry, I read your question more carefully and understood the problem differently.

Comment: thanks! I think this answers my question, but I think I still not understand why such test can be used? what assumptions we make? why reduce deviance by sacrifice degree of freedom can be "captured" using likelihood ratio / chisq ?

Comment: @hxd1011 not sure that can be answered, more or less in a comment. There's a lot of theory about LRTs. The deviance stat is related to the likelihood when not using "quasi" GLMs, compare the output of `anova` with your syntax above to the output of `2*logLik(fit1)` and the same for `fit2`.

Comment: I asked a separate question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326116/why-likelihood-ratio-statistic-satisfy-chisq-distribution). Could you help me with it when you have time?

Comment: @hxd1011 ah I saw your post and didn't realize the question is why the test statistic takes the known form of a Chi-square distribution. There is a rich discussion on that topic, especially with the linked question that I shared. I think it may be a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the link. it solved my problem! I did a search but did not find any..